# How to toggle between glyphicon classes

Tags: jquery, html, css

Hey I'm new to Jquery and was wondering how to toggle between a minus and plus glyphicon when I click a text (like a drop down menu).

The code is:

```
var main = function() {
  $('.day').click(function() {
    $(this).next().toggle();
    $('.weekday').find("span").toggle(function(){
      $(".glyphicon-plus").toggle();
      $(".glyphicon-minus").toggle();
    });
  });
};

$(document).ready(main);
```

In the html the glyphicon-plus is already on and the minus is not. This should switch between plus and minus when I press the text but instead the plus is disappearing then reappearing after one click.. can someone please help me?

Here is a snippet of the HTML:

```
<body>
    <div class="main">
      <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-sm-5 col-sm-offset-7">
            <h1>70&deg;</h1>
            <h2>5-day forecast</h2>
            <div class="forecast">

              <div class="day row">
                <div class="weekday col-xs-4">
                  <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></span>
                  <p>today</p>
                </div>
```

I want to toggle the

Comment: Please add your html structure also

Comment: Ok added a snippet of the html structure

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
$(this).find('i:first').toggleClass('glyphicon-plus glyphicon-minus');
```

[SAMPLE FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/5XqyW/266/)